# Continue to run after change window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension that executes some scripts.
my problem is when i change the document location the page load and don't continue the execution script.everything stop and don't change page location again.thanks for your help.

manifest

```
                 {
                "manifest_version": 2,
                "name": "My APP",  
                "description": "My APP",  
                "version": "1.0",    
                "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"], 

                 "background": {
                 "scripts": ["jquery-1.11.3.min.js"],

                "browser_action": { 
                    "default_popup": "popup.html"  
                } 
            }
```

popup.html

```
            <!doctype html>  
            <html>  
                <head><title>My App</title></head>  
            <body>  
                <button id="click">click</button>  
                <script src="popup.js"></script> 
            </body>
            </html>
```

popup.js

```
                function myScript() {
                    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
                });
            }

            document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', myScript);
```

content_script.js

```
            var Arr = ["xx1","xx2","xx3"];
            var Counter=0;

            function run() {
                window.location.href="http://www.cadpay.ir/page/request/" + Arr[++Counter] + "/";
                $(window).ready(function()
                {
                            document.body.getElementsByTagName('#send').click();    
                            alert('ok');                        
                });
                if( Arr.length > Counter)
                    run();
                else
                    alert('Finish');
            }

            run();
```

i changed some codes but didn't work.

popup.js

```
                function myScript() {

                var activeTabId;

                chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {


                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'window.location.href="https://www.cadpay.ir/req/22"'}, function (){

                    activeTabId = tab.id;
                });


                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
                    if( tabId === activeTabId )
                    {
                        activeTabId = null; 
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:"content_script.js"});
                    }
                });

            }

            document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', myScript);
```

and a question how do i control the loop ?

Comment: I think there was an almost duplicate question recently. Maybe you can find it. Basically you need to control the loop in the popup script and use `chrome.tabs.update` to change the url and inject only the `click()` line via `executeScript`.

Comment: Can you give me an example? i did it, but don't work.

Comment: Add your new code to the question or post it somewhere and link it in a comment.

Comment: i put popup.js code here! i think the problem is here!

Comment: function myScript() {
 
 var activeTabId;
 
 chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: 'window.location.href="http://www.cadpay.ir/page/request/12"'}, function (){
  activeTabId = tab.id;
    });
 
 
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if( tabId === activeTabId )
  {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:"content_script.js"});
  }
 });

}

document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', myScript);

Comment: [edit] your question to post the code.  Code in a comment is illegible.  A content script will unload on a page navigation.  You'll need to manage everything from the popup/background.

Comment: thanks! here your are.post updated!

Comment: Content scripts get unloaded and executed anew for every navigation of the tab. If you want processing that spans multiple page navigations you need to implement an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).